# A Color Puzzle for the Occasion!

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

I know this is a bit late, but puzzling SE's birthday is today or yesterday or really near right now, so I wrote out a birthday message for the site.

However, I accidentally spilled my unicorn frappuccino all over my computer screen, and the magicalness *(Disclaimer: This is probably not a word.)* of the unicorn bled into my screen, scrambling up all of my messages in meaningless letters and blobs of color.

Also, the unicorny *(this one isn't either)* powers of the unicorn frappuccino seemed to have boggled my brain a bit, making me forget what I was writing originally. Can you help me retrieve the message?

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e8Ha5YOYnLkhGLolxQN4fZSN14OgFaj--0ZhfgdxLPE/edit?usp=sharing

I've put the puzzle up as link form, for I do believe that the StackExchange uploading process does slightly distort the colors, so for maximum accuracy, I've decided to just provide a link to a spreadsheet.

Here, just in case, I'd like to note that the unicorn stuff isn't actually a part of the puzzle.

Also, not sure what tags to add to this puzzle.

Comment: I guess you take colors and order it something like RxGxB, but it took me an hour only to get red color, because i could not find any easy way for excel->hex :/

Answer (score 6):

I apologize as to how I first posted my answer.  This is a new account so it wouldn't let me post a comment instead.  I realize you're probably only supposed to post full answers but this has been up for a year so I didn't think it would matter much.

> Putting the colors in the proper order (nothing to do with hex codes as the OP was concerned the the colors *displaying* correctly gives you the following text string: 1ptupQ2kxCLMwquMEEMrXF_bVRYwVSuVYbfd4s_xbYS0

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J5ylM3WO1Gqcq9HdcFw5xvT4wpNz9d2uBFxVywq_93w/edit?usp=sharing

> Placing this into the URL gives us Step 2:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ptupQ2kxCLMwquMEEMrXF_bVRYwVSuVYbfd4s_xbYS0/

All I got so far.  Really need to get some sleep.  Will post the rest later hopefully.

ETA:  So annoying that I can't comment.  Got my first edit all typed up and them saw Fifth_H0r5eman's comment.  I wasn't sure too how formal this site was, so after my first post I was second-guessing myself with my chattiness and rambling.  Thought maybe I should have stuck to the answer only so I went back and made the edit (plus I had actually figured out the first part!)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Way to take the initiative on an old, unsolved mystery! Hopefully your post will give ideas to some of the other puzzlers out there (it did for me).

Comment: @Kacee rot 13 gur neenatrzrag lbh unir vf gur cngu gb gur arkg fgrc, gur arkg rkpry qbp. I would do it, but I don't have the time at the moment. Good luck!

Comment: @Kacee, You can comment on your own answers, so no need to update your answer with comments. I'm not yet an expert, but I've never seen partial answers complained about while a puzzle is being solved. It's copied or repeated answers that get downvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

Working from Kacee's attempt:

> Copying the ordered text string into the google docs html gives  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ptupQ2kxCLMwquMEEMrXF_bVRYwVSuVYbfd4s_xbYS0/edit?usp=sharing

Leading to

> Second Step, a grid version. It appears that the difference in some of the blues is less than a couple of RGB points, and impossible to distinguish into a spectrum by eye, leading me to believe there is something else to be done here... Also there are 66 characters, whereas Doc URLs require 44. The underscore and leads me to think URL however.